# Amazon rds MySql -> concurrent connections deadlocks

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading, amazon-rds

I've built an application in C#.NET that uses MySql as a database. My application inserts and updates data in the database in a using the Parallel API (so multithreaded). For reference, the queries that are being fired multithreaded would look like:

```
Update User set IsActive = 1 where UserID = 1 --each thread updates a different user id
```

This has always worked on servers that I manage and development machines.

We recently migrated the MySql database to Amazon RDS, however. Since then, if I run this query multithreaded (even with as low as two concurrent threads), it throws an exception:

```
Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

Any experience with this issue? Are there some settings in Amazon RDS which are configured differently from a default MySql installation?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I have posted the same question on dba.stackexchange.com - I hope that is ok with the mods!